# Not writing (or even opening file) in php

Tags: php, html, web-deployment, writetofile

I read many of the other questions on this site revolving around this error, none of which were able to help me, The below php code takes the data input from the html file and sends it to the php file, after printing "Hello Name" on the page, it should open a file called My_file.txt, which is already created, and write to it, I have been unable to do so, any help would be great, here is my code:

index.html file:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello Friend</title></head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<p style="text-align:center">
<font color="white">
<form action="data.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

data.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Friend, this is php</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<font color="white">
<code>
<?php
    $name = $_POST["myname"];
    echo "Hello, " . $name;
    $filename = "My_file.txt";
    chmod($filename, 777);
    $f = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file");
    fwrite($f, "The Name is: " . $name);
    f.close($f);
    echo fgets($f);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

Output:

```
Hello, JohnUnable to open file
```

Comment: Did you turn error reporting on?

Answer (score 0):

You want to open file for write. Make sure file is writable by this php process. Check out your http server rights on that script folder where data.php appears. Also enable more verbose php errors, this can be related to many things (maybe your hosting disabled fopen feature).

Comment: I am on Linux I installed php & apache2 via apt-get install, I do not see a debug option, how would I go amongst doing that?

Comment: I would suggest do something like `chmod -R 777 /var/www` for testing purposes. If it works - then there is permission problem that you can fix later. Take a look on `/var/log/apache2/*` files, maybe there is something you can inspect.